# Sharing temporary tables between connections

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to share temporary variables between several database connections?

I have a connection pool, however the nature of my queries make it necessary to a significant amount of temporary tables for each query (but they are the same for all queries). By using the connection pool I don't have access to the temporary tables. Is there some good way to circumvent this problem while still using the connection pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to come up with a different solution. Temporary tables specific to each connection and can't be shared.